# Operating on internal tables with header line

Tags: append, structure, abap, internal-tables

I have a question about internal tables' header line.
I assigned some values into `in_table1` and then try to add a record with `APPEND` command into `in_table2` in the following block of code.
But I cannot see the record that I have appended into `in_table2`.
Is this because of the header line of `in_table2`?
If yes, how can I see the records anyway?

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report  ZTEST_LOOP
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

REPORT  ZTEST_STRUCT_DATA_TYPE.

***** define structure data types

TYPES: BEGIN OF adres_bilgileri, " this is a struct with a set of types
  sokak type c length 30,
  cadde type c length 30,
  sehir type c length 15,
  ev_no type n length 4,
  end of adres_bilgileri.

  types: BEGIN OF personel_bilgileri,
    ad type c LENGTH 20,
    soyad type c LENGTH 20,
    tel_no type n LENGTH 12,
    adres TYPE adres_bilgileri," ********************!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    END OF personel_bilgileri.

TYPES personel_bilgi_tablosu TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF personel_bilgileri WITH key TABLE_LINE.
  data: in_table1 type personel_bilgileri,
        in_table2 type personel_bilgi_tablosu WITH HEADER LINE.
        "adres1 type adres_bilgileri.


 in_table1-ad = 'Latife'.
 in_table1-soyad = 'A'.
 in_table1-adres-sokak = 'Hasanpaşa'. """"""""""""adresten sokak bilgisine geçiş
 in_table1-adres-ev_no = 10.

 append in_table1 to in_table2.

  WRITE / :  'Records in in_table2:', in_table2.
```

Comment: First of all, you should not use the internal tables with headers anymore. Second of all you are printing the header `in_table2` which is of course empty. If you want to print the contents of table `in_table2[]` you have too loop through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not use internal tables with header anymore.

Second of all, if you really have to do it, here is some solution.

The header `in_table2` is of course empty in your case. You have to loop through the table to print it out. For example like this.

```
LOOP AT in_table2.   "here in_table2 means table (an internal table)
  WRITE / in_table2. "here in_table2 means the header of the table (a structure)
ENDLOOP.
```

Internal tables with headers should not be used exactly because of this confusion. Looks like you got confused exactly in such way. The meaning of `in_table2` is ambiguous and depends on the context.

Better use field symbols for looping and appending.

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_for_loop> LIKE LINE OF in_table2[].
LOOP AT in_table2[] ASSIGNING <fs_for_loop>.
  WRITE / <fs_for_loop>.
ENDLOOP.
```